# C++ int vector to c#

Tags: c#, c++, function, call

I'm doing a C# project and I want to call `next_permutation` from the algorithm library in C++. I found the way to call c++ functions in c# but i dont know how to get vectors from c++ and use it in c# (cause next_permutation require a int vector...)

this is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
extern void NextPermutation(vector<int>& permutation) 
{
    next_permutation (permutation.begin(),permutation.end()); 
}

[DllImport("PEDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void NextPermutation(IntPtr test);
```

Comment: you need some glue to convert it. Why not just do it in C#? Google give me this: http://code.google.com/p/monoalgorithm/source/browse/trunk/Algorithm.cs?spec=svn2&r=2#163

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing this is via a C++/CLI wrapper class.  You will have to convert an int[] or List< int > to a std::vector as a seperate pass, however.  If there is a lot of data in the vector you are passing in ... it WILL cause a SIGNIFICANT slow down.

Answer (score 1):

P/Invoke is very bad for C++ types. You should try to simplify your problems into a C interface. In your case, this is very easy!

```
extern void NextPermutation(int *permutation, int count) 
{
    next_permutation (permutation, permutation + count); 
}
```